# Autocomplete history in rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

a google search did not help me out so i'm hoping our community will...

i'm new to rstudio and while its easy to just press the up button to go back sequentially through r commands when the command you are looking for is just a few commands back, it's hard when the command is a while back.

I'm looking for something like ctrl-R in linux environments where you type a few letters and it completes your command based on your history.

is there something like this in rstudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `history()`

For e.g

```
history(max.show = 50, reverse = F, pattern = "data.table::")
```

This will automatically open the commands used in the past .

Answer (score 0):

You can search in your history in RStudio

[image]

Comment: did not see this feature! i'll wait to see if there is also a command... if not i'll accept this as the right answer